# jQuery: Pause sound with button click instead of restart

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery for playing sound. If I click my `.sound_control` button a few times, the sound always restarts from the beginning. I would need a pause function instead of that.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var background_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  background_sound.src = "https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/airport-gate-1.mp3";
  background_sound.volume = 0.1;
  background_sound.autoPlay = true;
  background_sound.loop = true;
  background_sound.controls = true;
  background_sound.play();


  var click_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  click_sound.src = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3";
  click_sound.volume = 0.1;
  click_sound.autoPlay = false;
  click_sound.preLoad = true;
  click_sound.controls = true;


  $(".click_sound").click(function() {
    click_sound.currentTime = 0;
    click_sound.play();
  });

  $(".sound_control").click(function() {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (background_sound.currentTime) {
      background_sound.currentTime = 0;
      background_sound.pause();
    } else {
      background_sound.play();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.on_off:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sound_control">Sound <span class="on_off">on</span><span class="on_off">off</span></button>

<button class="click_sound">Button One</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Two</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Three</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Four</button>
```

How is it possible to do that? Would be very happy if someone could help me!

Comment: You could just remove the ```sound.currentTime = 0;``` in your code.

Comment: @Stormix – Thank you! I updated my code. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I posted answer, think I found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement has for some reason the side effect of stopping playback, I'm not a 100% sure why, but here's what you should use instead:

```js
$(".sound_control").click(function() {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (!background_sound.paused) {
      background_sound.pause();
    } else {
      background_sound.play();
    }
  });
```

#### Edit: mute click sound when sound is off.

Since we're using the background sound as an indicator on whether the sound is **on** or **off**. We can just add an extra check to the *click_sound* handler.

```js
 $(".click_sound").click(function() {
    if(!background_sound.paused){
      click_sound.currentTime = 0;
      click_sound.play();
    }
  });
```

Here's a live snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var background_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  background_sound.src = "https://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/airport-gate-1.mp3";
  background_sound.volume = 0.1;
  background_sound.autoPlay = true;
  background_sound.loop = false;
  background_sound.controls = true;
  background_sound.play();


  var click_sound = document.createElement("audio");
  click_sound.src = "http://soundbible.com/mp3/Stapler-SoundBible.com-374581609.mp3";
  click_sound.volume = 0.1;
  click_sound.autoPlay = true;
  click_sound.preLoad = true;
  click_sound.controls = true;

  $(".click_sound").click(function() {
    if(!background_sound.paused){
      click_sound.currentTime = 0;
      click_sound.play();
    }
  });

  $(".sound_control").click(function() {
    $(".on_off").toggle();
    if (!background_sound.paused) {
      background_sound.pause();
    } else {
      background_sound.play();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.on_off:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sound_control">Sound <span class="on_off">on</span><span class="on_off">off</span></button>

<button class="click_sound">Button One</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Two</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Three</button>
<button class="click_sound">Button Four</button>
```

Comment: Thank you again! One thing is missing now: The click sound should also be only audible if sound is "on".

Comment: I've found another issue. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari, there is an autoplay. How is it possible to avoid the autoplay?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the current time to 0.

**sound.currentTime = 0;**

And in this snippet you did not define sound.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I updated my code. Doesn't work in this case ...